# Embedded PDF viewer in Texmaker not working correctly

Tags: document-configuration

I am new to LaTeX world.

I have set Texmaker (installed on windows 8.1) to show source editor and embedded pdf viewer on same window.

Now whenever I Press "Run", the embedded PDF viewer window do not show the output PDF.

It only display the output PDF whenever i reopen it by "File>Open Recent".

I have posted a screenshot regarding this,

I deleted the equation in my sample document and saved it and pressed "RUN" but right window did not show the changes made by me.

It is still showing the equation deleted previously.
[image]

any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of what i did to resolve my query:

On Tools Toolbar i chose "Quick Build" from drop-down menu next to the "Run" command.Now on "Run", changes in my document are visible instantly.

(P.S.: This is a mistake which can only be expected from a novice user (someone like me)).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. **I FOUND A FIX**. I uninstalled and reinstalled TexMaker and MikTeX many times. Nothing worked. Then, simply in TexMaker go to Options -> Settings File -> Reset Settings. Then it restarts TexMaker and it works. I know, I couldn't believe it either, since I had just reinstalled it fresh a minute before.

Comment: If you want to keep your settings, you can first `save a copy of your settings file`, then reset and load it again

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether the embedded viewer knows to reload the PDF upon changes, you will or will not see the change in your document instantly. What happens if you: make a change, save, press "PDFLaTeX" and then press "View PDF"?

What I can say for sure is that the problem is related either to TeXMaker itself, or to your usage of the software (meaning that this should not happen). If what I suggested above does not work, or if this is not acceptable to you, I would then suggest either of the following:

- Giving up on the embedded preview in TeXMaker, and either continue to use TeXMaker for editing only (or change editor altogether), and use an independent PDF viewer that reloads automatically like [SumatraPDF](http://sumatra-pdf.en.softonic.com/).
- If you like the idea of having the source and the compiled document side by side (and given that you're not an Emacs person I assume), you might be interested in web applications like [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) as well, which will also allow you to keep your documents on the cloud free of charge.